# Is it permissible to use Qur'anic quotes as decorations?

Tags: halal-haram, quran

Can I decorate my home or working place with Islamic elements?
 For example, using suras or words from the Qur'an, or kahbatullah pictures, or various du'as as both decoration and as a reminder so that we don't forget?

Comment: Whats the intention behind it, is it for decoration or as a reminder?

Answer (score -1):

Peace be upon you,
If your intention is to decorate your home by this, then it is sinful. But if your intention is to receive Allah's blessings, then it is fine.
This is what I have heard from a scholar. And Allah knows best.

Comment: Source would be nice, but i do believe in that same opinion since one of the many things we are judged upon is our intentions.

Comment: I'm sure there are people who hold a different view. As @Musk suggested, please cite your evidences. Which scholar did you hear this from?