# Hanging kaaba and other holy places or dua pictures

Tags: source-identification, islamic-philosophy

I know the fact that pictures are not allowed in islam, also that in islam you cannot draw pictures. But i lack wisdom on subject of people hanging kaaba, madina or kalma pictures in home. Some people also hang ayatul kursi or 4 quls. Is it ok and permissible or not and if not, is there any reference?

Comment: My dear friend only Drawing Pictures of living creatures is prohibited .

Comment: @zia I have heard that you should hang picture of family, living ones.

Comment: photographic/digital pic and drawing are different things my friend

Comment: Related post http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30640/is-it-permissible-to-use-quranic-quotes-as-decoration